# How to get loading time of each component of a page from server side in cq5

Tags: java, aem

How to get loading time of each component of a page in CQ5 from server side.

Here as per my implementation we are getting longest time taking to load page from request.log file. But i need to get each component loading time of page from server side.

I found this link but this will work from client side:
http://www.wemblog.com/2014/05/how-to-find-component-load-time-on-page.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to include logger for every component tag class call and provide stopwatch for entry and exit of the call.

```
Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classname.class);
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch("new");
stopWatch.start();
stopWatch.stop();
```

Once you included this in your tag class you could able to find the time taken for each component in a particular page.
You can use putty for accessing your server log.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version AEM 6.0, there is OOTB feature to measure rendering time for each component on a page.

It is accessible through TouchUI, Developer mode.

[image]

However, it won't work if AEM is installed with run mode 'nosamplecontent'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RequestProgressTracker`, as explained in the [Sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/request-analysis.html)

It's obtainable from [`SlingHttpServletRequest#getRequestProgressTracker`](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletRequest.html#getRequestProgressTracker()). In order to get the timing stats for your components, you can use a [Servlet Filter](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html) to execute the code on every request.

Whenever the filter is called:

1. Get the `RequestProgressTracker` from the request object
2. Call `getMessages` to obtain an iterator over a collection of request progress messages for the current request
3. Analyze the messages to find the resource types and timing information. Unfortunately, every message is only available as a `String` so you'll need to parse it to get the data.

Let's have a look at some example messages from the docs:

[image: example RequestProgressTracket output]

The last message is the kind we're looking for:

```
TIMER_END{103,/libs/sling/servlet/default/explorer/node.esp#0}
```

The number `103` is the number of milliseconds the script took to execute. The value after the comma is the script. You can tailor a regular expression to extract both values from every such message.

One of the projects I recently worked on used this approach to report on component performance. We had a neat dashboard in NewRelic with live stats on every component we built.